# Can I check out only part of a Git repository?

Tags: git, github

I have recently changed over to a platform, Cloud9, for my school projects, and more. Unfortunately it only 512MB of storage for free users.

Halfway through, I am exceeding the disk quota so I removed all my previous work and started a clean workspace. I would like to add my new projects into the same remote repository (for easy organizational purposes).

Is there a workaround (or hack) for me to stage, commit changes, and merge* (I'm not trying to forcibly overwrite) them into the remote repository without having all the files on the local repository?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to clone a git repository's sub-directory only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/is-there-any-way-to-clone-a-git-repositorys-sub-directory-only)

Comment: Possibly you have to choose between "easy organizational purpose" and reasonable splitting repository into several parts in this case ...

Comment: @isherwood Thank you - I think sparse checkout might be what I'm looking for, but I can't seem to push subdirectories back into the remote repository.

Answer (score 1):

You may try using git shallow copy - `git clone --depth 1 <remote>`